# What is the common encrypt/decrypt technique for CakePHP 3 and Angular 6?

Tags: angular, cakephp

I plan to encrypt data in CakePHP 3 and need to decrypt on Angular 6. Also, Viceversa.

Please share your thought if you have this experience.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm no Angular expert, but it runs on the client side, right? Meaning that the encryption key would need to be available to the client. How do you get that key there securely, and couldn't you instead use that process to get the decrypted thing there, skipping all the encryption complexity?

Answer (score 0):

cakephp has Security Utility which provide encryption and decryption using `AES-256` here is an example from cakephp doc

**Encryption**

```
//$value is the data 
//Assuming key is stored somewhere it can be re-used for
$key = 'wt1U5MACWJFTXGenFoZoiLwQGrLgdbHA';
$result = Security::encrypt($value, $key);
```

**Decryption**

```
$key = 'wt1U5MACWJFTXGenFoZoiLwQGrLgdbHA';

$cipher = $user->secrets;
$result = Security::decrypt($cipher, $key);
```

Encryption in Cakephp will use either **openssl** or **mcrypt** based on what is available on your system but  **mcrypt** extension has been deprecated in PHP7.1

for more information please check 
[Encrypting and Decrypting Data using Cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/security.html#encrypting-and-decrypting-data)

**Javascript**
If you are looking for how to use it with Javascript frameworks you should look for a library can decrypt AES and here is an example

https://github.com/JamesMGreene/node-aes256

```
var decrypted = aes256.decrypt(key, encrypted);
```

key is the one you use it in CakePHP and the encrypted is the encrypted data.
sorry im not AngularJS developer but you can use it on this way.

Comment: How will it be decrypted in angular 6?